# Android force ActionBar inside of Toolbar on Landscape

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, landscape

The example code found on https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare results in my tablet to look like this:

[image]

However I want it to look like this :

[image]

Relevant xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Relevant code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ...

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    if (viewPager != null) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Category 3");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //...

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

What do I have to change/add to the layout/code to make the toolbar contain the tabs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toolbar is a FrameLayout. Put the tabs inside the Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: You may want to consider setting the height of the TabLayout to match_parent, so that it doesn't exceed 40dp in landscape orientation.

Comment: @pdegand59 Toolbar is a custom ViewGroup ;)